# Error when using vba for index match formula with cell address

Tags: excel, vba

Excel keeps throwing me:

> Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error

every time I try to run the below code. I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong (would really appreciate any advice).

Is it a problem in the way I am defining the `skumaestro` range?

Thanks

```
Sub getskus ()
lastskurow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
lasthandlerow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row


With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

    Dim skumaestro As Range
    Set skumaestro = Range(Cells(lasthandlerow, 13), Cells(lastskurow, 13))

End With
For start = 1 To count

     Range("C" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
     ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(" & barcodes.Address(True, True, 
      xlA1, True) & ",MATCH(" & skumaestro(1).Address(False, True, xlA1, 
      False) & "," & skucodes.Address(True, True, xlA1, True) & ",0))"

     ActiveCell.Value2 = ActiveCell.Value2 

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What are `barcodes` and `skucodes`? Seems like there's code missing here. Also first two lines should be within a `With...End With` block.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the With ... End With block correctly. Note the `.` which allow .Range and .Cells to inherit the parent worksheet.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

    Dim skumaestro As Range
    Set skumaestro = .Range(.Cells(lasthandlerow, 13), .Cells(lastskurow, 13))

End With
```

Your formula uses xlA1 addresses to try and construct a FormulaR1C1 formula. There is no defined parent worksheet. *barcodes* and *skucodes* are undefined. You aren't using *start* to cycle through anything.

I think you want something like,

```
For start = 1 To count

     with Range("C" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)   'what parent worksheet?

         .FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(" & barcodes.Address(True, True, 
      xlR1C1, True) & ",MATCH(" & skumaestro(start).Address(False, True, xlR1C1, 
      False) & "," & skucodes.Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True) & ",0))"

         .Value = .Value2 

    end with

Next start
```

You aren't using an external address for *skumaestro* in the formula so it can reasonably be assumed that the formula was intended for the same worksheet used above.

```
Dim skumaestro As Range, addr1 as string, addr2 as string

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

    Set skumaestro = .Range(.Cells(lasthandlerow, 13), .Cells(lastskurow, 13))
    addr1 = barcodes.Address(True, True, xlR1C1, external:=True)
    addr2 = skucodes.Address(True, True, xlR1C1, external:=True)

     with .Range("C" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).resize(count, 1)

         .FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(" & addr1 & ",MATCH(" & skumaestro(1).Address(False, True, xlR1C1, False) & "," & addr2 & ",0))"
         .Value = .Value2 

    end with

End With
```